# Object visible in Outliner but not in 3D Viewport

Tags: 3d-view, outliner

As you can see from the photo, there are 3 objects in the Outliner that don't show up in the viewport, while I was preparing the rest of the donuts, they just got lost in the middle of the process, and I couldn't find them after that, however they appeared in the rendered image. 
[image: view from blender][image: rendered image]

Comment: Is this by any chance an emitter in a particle system ?

Comment: @Gorgious yes there is actually!

Comment: In the particle system settings, there is a check somewhere that says "Show Emitter". Make sure it is on to see it in viewport :)

Comment: @Gorgious I just checked and it's on.. Still can't see those objects in the viewport. :/